# Найдите ошибку в коде, пожалуйста

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
a=[]
b=int(input())
for i in range(b):
    a.append(input())
a=sorted(a)
for i in range(b):
    print(a[i])
```

При вводе: 4 34 243 43 292

Выдает: 243
292
34
43

Должно: 292
243
43
34

(Программа выводит числа в порядке убывания)

Comment: Не числа, а строки. `input` возвращает строку, и переменной `b` вы преобразуете строку в число, а для элементов списка `a` почему-то решили этого не делать

Comment: Вы их в массив помещаете как строки, как строки они и сортируются, все правильно программа делает, все как вы и написали. Про информативность заголовков вам уже говорили, кстати.

Comment: Вместо `a=sorted(a)` просто пишите `a.sort()`  возможно, чуть быстрее (копии не создается), но буковок точно меньше :)

Comment: Судя по желательномк результату в функцию сортровки надо добавить аргумент `(reverse=True)`

Comment: *"Найдите ошибку в коде, пожалуйста"* чересчур расплывчатый заголовок. Попробуйте выбрать что-то более близкое к вашей проблеме (*что* ваш код должен делать). [ask] Отредактируйте вопрос и словами опишите желаемое поведение, нажмите [edit]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Боюсь, что заминусят за ответ на детский вопрос, но подытоживая советы коллег, которым я поставил "лайк", можно написать примерно так:

```
a=[]
b=int(input())
for i in range(b):
    a.append(int(input()))
a.sort(reverse=True)
for q in a:
    print(q)
```

Проблема кода (как уже говорилось) в том, что вы забыли при вводе конвертировать стоки в числа. В результате - сравнение отрабатывало правильно по правилам сравнения строк.

Comment: Чтобы не заминусовали надо писать решениев одну строчку! :)  Такое как лабораторку не примут... `[print(x) for x in sorted([int(input()) for _ in range(int(input()))], reverse=True)]`

Comment: Браво @AlexTitov!
в следующий раз так и буду делать....
Благодарю за мудрый совет  ;-)

Comment: отвечаешь - отвечаешь и получаешь только минуса....

Comment: @VasylKolomiets: я больше 10 лет на вопросы отвечаю и всё равно минуса получаю -- не стоит обращать внимания. Я правда не вижу пользы ни в вопросе, ни в ответе (ни автору -- не сказано в ответе в чём проблема была и как ваш код её исправляет,  ни другим людям -- нет словесного описания проблемы, что затруднит поиск ответа)